Strength of a phase-transition
I'm currently studying neutron stars for a summer research project, and it uses the terms 'weak' and 'strong' transition for nuclear matter in its literature. Can someone explain (in terms that a rising junior majoring in physics can understand), what is meant by the strength of a phase transition? I googled and found a couple of research papers but was very lost in the mathematics.

Do you understand what is meant by first order and second order phase transitions?

I do, but only superficially. I understand their definitions though (the mathematical ones).

In real life there are no perfectly first order or second order transitions. There is a continuous scale between them. I think, though I am not sure, that when discussing neutron stars a strong transition is closer to the ideal first order transition than a  weak transition.

Maybe picking up on John Rennies (correct) comments about first and second order phase transitions in the present context. When discussing neutron stars and especially their equation of state (EoS), which is linked to properties like mass and radius of isolated neutron stars, I think the "strength" of a phase transition -- in this context at least -- is typically linked to the discontinuity in the energy density at the transition. The phase transitions occur at a fixed pressure $P_c$ where the system undergoes a change from one phase to another. If the transition is second order the energy density does not jump $\epsilon_1(P_c)=\epsilon_2(P_c)$ also in accordance with the Ehrenfest classification. At the first order transition however the energy density does jump $\epsilon_1(P_c)<\epsilon_2(P_c)$, which is a clear signal for a first order phase transition and is also related to phase coexistence a the transition.
In terms of strength: a second order transition is weak or even weakest while first order transitions are stronger. When comparing two first order transitions in terms of strength: the one with the bigger jump in energy density is stronger than the other.
What does that mean for neutron stars? Well neutron stars are stabilized against gravitational collapse by the pressure generated of the matter inside them. A so called stiff EoS generates a high pressure for a given energy density. Compared to this a soft EoS creates a lower pressure at the same energy density. Stiff EoS can support more massive stars, since they can compensate higher gravitational forces. Any jump in energy density softens the EoS. In that sense a strong phase transition leads to a softening of the EoS and thus less massive stable stars. So EoS with strong phase transitions (depending on the model and type of matter we are talking about) might have problems describing massive neutron stars (the ones with masses beyond two solar masses).
